# How to find from GUI whether Client Side scripting or server side scripting is running

Tags: asp.net, browser, client, webclient

We have a GUI which runs on ASP.NET 2.0 framework (Client-Server model). From the support perspective how can one find whether the pages which are opening on GUI at any point of time is a server side scripting or Client side scripting.

The reason why I ask this is because I understand that some of the codes are executed by the browser such as Javascript. So, if there are such scripts which are handled by the client browser, how can one find out that it is the Client side scripting which is running at that moment.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the server there's no way to find if a client-side script is currently executing. Http is stateless.

On the client you can use browser's window.load even to check if the page is completely loaded, still you cannot say for sure that server-side script was running until then, Because it also takes time to load the script-response into browser. But you can check how much time did a serverside-script take to execute by some timer gimmicks on the server-side script.